# ConstraintLayout - Even Space Between Buttons

Tags: android, button, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to make space between 2 buttons (Send and Clear) to be even. 
It's adjusting to borders and vertical guideline which is in the center of the screen. 
It seems to be fine on the project but it doesn't look like that in the app itself. 
Please check below screenshots.

[Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gsac7.png)

[App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKT7K.png)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.f3nr1r.testkeyboard.MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonClear"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="clearText"
        android:text="Clear"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="sendInput"
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button8"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="sendInput"
        android:text="9"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button8"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="sendInput"
        android:text="7"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button8" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="sendInput"
        android:text="6"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="sendInput"
        android:text="5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="sendInput"
        android:text="8"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="sendInput"
        android:text="4"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button5" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Type something here..."
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="sendInput"
        android:text="3"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="sendInput"
        android:text="2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="sendInput"
        android:text="1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSend"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="sendText"
        android:text="Send"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="192dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="154dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Post your layout xml

Comment: @FerdousAhamed Posted, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. 
Constraint to the middle guideline should be removed and you can adjust the place with margins. 
In XML, below lines should be removed from these buttons ("buttonSend" and "buttonClear").

```
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline2"
app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline2"
```